# Creating a dropdown menu from json data

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu, menu

I am looking to display the data from "conta", "zip, city, street_a, street_b", "count, number" and create a drop-down menu from the "contact" keys, but this is getting no where, can someone explain how this would work, this is the far I got with what I have.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery</title>
<!-- script type='text/javascript' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

data = [
{"conta":"13356","name":"MISS Two"},
{"zip":"01111","city":"NASHUA, MA","street_a":"10 MAIN ROAD SQUARE","street_b":"Nothing"},
{"count":"544","number":"250"},
[
  {"contact":"Mark Bre"},
  {"contact":"Mary Lou"},
  {"contact":"John Ton"},
  {"contact":"Carls Des"},
  {"contact":"Carlos Drt"}
 ]
] 

$('body').append('<select id="dynamicSelect"></select>');
var options="";
$.each(data,function(i1,val1){
   if($.isArray(val1)){
      $.each(data,function(i2,val2){
           options += "<option value="+ val2.contact +">" + val2.contact + "</option>"
      });
   }
}
$('#dynamicSelect').append(options);

</script>
</head>

<body>
The Select:<select id="dynamicSelect">
<option value="option value" selected="selected">option html</option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you check if the main array element is an array, you then pass the main array to the `each` to create the options, not the nested array

Change:

```
if($.isArray(val1)){
      $.each(data,function(i2,val2){
           options += "<option value="+ val2.contact +">" + val2.contact + "</option>"
      });
}
```

TO:

```
if($.isArray(val1)){
      /* loop over "val1"*/
      $.each(val1,function(i2,val2){
           options += "<option value="+ val2.contact +">" + val2.contact + "</option>"
      });
}
```

ALso you need to wrap your code in `docment.ready`, the code is firing before the `select` tag exists

WRap all code in

```
$(function(){
   /* run code here*/

});
```

You are missing some closing braces for first `each`. Use browser console to check for errors thrown

Comment: Got that and to grab the other elements of the data; "conta", "zip, city, street_a, street_b", "count, number" it should loop where in the array?

Answer (score 0):

First, there were a few errors in your JS code.

- You need to terminate the function inside of your outer each with a `)`
- The inner call to `.each()` should iterate over `val1` and not `data` again

**JS**

```
// Dynamically add a label for the select to the body
var label = $('<label id="dynamicSelectLabel" for="dynamicSelect">The Select</label>').appendTo('body');
// Dynamically add the select to the body
var select = $('<select id="dynamicSelect"></select>').appendTo('body');
// For each value in the data array
$.each(data, function (i1, val1) {
    // If the value is an array
    if ($.isArray(val1)) {
        // For each value in the contact array
        $.each(val1, function (i2, val2) {
            // Add an option to the select with the contact name and value
            select.append('<option value=' + val2.contact + '>' + val2.contact + '</option>');
        });
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H7n6b/1/)**